# How to set minimumDate and maximumDate qml

Tags: qt, datepicker, calendar, qml

I got stuck when I was trying to set the minimumDate of my calendar.

```
Calendar{        
    id:calendarioDX
    frameVisible :false
    width:dp(260)
    height:parent.height*0.26
    anchors.right: parent.right; anchors.rightMargin: parent.width*0.03
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
}
```

This is my calendar with basics property and i want to set the minimumDate. How can i do that with qml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor, for example:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Calendar {
        minimumDate: new Date(2017, 0, 1)
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```